# Pyodbc doesn't run the procedure correctly without even throwing any error

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a SQL Server procedure which runs in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) without any problem and every time it generates the same table.

I want to run the same procedure using python and `pyodbc`. In order to do that I wrote a python function `run_procedure(my_procedure)` which runs the procedure.

The problem is, every time I run the python function,
I get a different result!

The procedure:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure_create_tbl_date_range;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_create_tbl_date_range
AS
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_date_range;


   DECLARE @dateFrom date;
   DECLARE @dateTo date;

   SET @dateFrom = '2021-12-12';
   SET @dateTo   = '2022-12-12';

   create table tbl_date_range (dates_ date);

   WHILE(@dateFrom < @dateTo)
   BEGIN
      SELECT @dateFrom = DATEADD(day, 1,@dateFrom)
      INSERT INTO tbl_date_range 
      SELECT @dateFrom
   END;

GO
```

The python function:

```py
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

def run_procedure(my_procedure):
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                        'Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;'
                        'Database=my_db;'
                        'Trusted_Connection=yes'
                        )

    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        res = cur.execute(my_procedure)
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cur.close()
        del cur
        conn.close()
```

Now almost each time I run the function below, the query `SELECT max(dates_) as max_date_ FROM tbl_date_range` returns a different result!

```
run_procedure("EXEC procedure_create_tbl_date_range")
```

First try:

[image]

Second try:

[image]

Does anyone know, why the result is different?!

Comment: This is not possible given what you have stated. Are you sure you are connecting to the right database? Is the above code your *actual* code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. 
Yes: I am connecting to the right database.
My actual code has only two differences: 
1. I have another function which uses `pd.read_sql` to run the query stated in the question. both of these two python functions use the same connection string. 
2. I have changed the database name. But I am sure I am using the same database while running both the procedure and the query.

Comment: For a procedure which doesn't return data you shouldn't use `read_sql` because it might not wait for all resultsets. Also what happens if you put `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the top of the procedure

Comment: First of all thanks a lot:) the `SET NOCOUNT ON;` solved the problem:) Yesterday I had to run all my 20 procedures manually! If you haven't solved it, I would have to do it every week! Second: Even when I run the `run_procedure(my_procedure)`, and wait for 10 seconds and then run the query directly in Azure Data Explorer, it still shows me wrong answer! Thanks you again. It was a great help... How we go further? You would write the answer and I approve it?